# Impedir do usuário trocar de campo antes de completar

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

Em alguns formulários específicos, quero validar se usuário preencheu o campo por completo.

Caso ele saia do `input`, um alerta na tela é exibido, e então o foco volta para esse campo.

Tentei fazer isso com o **JavaScript** abaixo, mas não funcionou como eu quero.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function validaHora(x){
 if (x.value.length(5)){
  alert ("ERRO!");
  x.focus();
  return false;
 }else{
  alert ("OK!");
  return true;
 }
}
</script>
```

no input

```
@onblur = "return ValidaHora(this)"
```

Comment: Qual é o critério de "preencher por completo"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vejo alguns problemas no seu código. Primeiro que o nome da função chamada no `onblur` é diferente do nome da função:

```
@onblur = "return ValidaHora(this)" <-- "V" maiúsculo
                  ↑
function validaHora(x){             <-- "v" minúsculo
         ↑
```

Se não foi erro de digitação da pergunta, só aí já daria erro de *função inexistente* e o código não iria funcionar.

Mas se foi apenas erro de digitação da pergunta e os nomes são iguais no código, daria erro no `x.value.length(5)`: o `.length` não é uma função, logo não tem `()` após, seria apenas `x.value.length`.

Outro problema é no uso do `alert` com `.focus()`, porque isso vai travar a página disparando o `alert` seguidas e infinitas vezes, porque quando a condicional do `if` for satisfeita, o campo irá ganhar foco e ao clicar para fechar o `alert`, o campo perderá o foco chamando novamente a função e entrando novamente no `if`, criando um loop infinito onde a caixa de alerta ficará sendo exibida continuamente, travando a aba.

Uma forma de evitar isso, além das devidas correções mencionadas, é criar um *flag* (variável de controle) para impedir que o `alert` seja disparado novamente ao fechá-lo:

```js
var alerta; // flag
function ValidaHora(x){
   if (x.value.length < 5){
      if(!alerta){
         alerta = true;
         alert("ERRO!");
         setTimeout(function(){
            x.focus();
            alerta = false;
         }, 1);
      }
      return false;
   }else{
      alert("OK!");
      return true;
   }
}
```

```html
Mínimo 5 caracteres:<br>
<input onblur="return ValidaHora(this)">
```

Answer (score 2):

Aqui tem uma opção bem simples, se o cara clicar no `input` e depois clicar cora e o `input` for inválido ele da uma `alert`. Tipo no `.blur` do `input` vc faz um `if .is(":invalid")` e mostra ou não o alerta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```js
$('input').blur(function (el) {
 if ($(el.target).is(":invalid")) {
                this.focus();
  console.log('pelo menos 10 letras');
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="" type="text" minlength="10" required>
<input id="" type="text" minlength="10" required>
<input id="" type="text" minlength="10" required>
```